# compare means of lognormal distribution

Tags: mean, lognormal-distribution

I have a small set of data that I used to generated a lognormal distribution:

```r
x <- c(15.9,  11.8,   0.99,   3.41,   7.94,   3.4,  1.3,
       6.49,  0.815,  10.7, 4.44, 2.28, 3.3,  3.92, 2.18, 3.28, 8.01)
ns    <-  10000
mS    <-  mean(log(x)) 
sdS   <-  sdlog <- log(sd(x))

obs   <- rlnorm(ns, mS, sdS)
```

I need to compare the mean of samples extracted from `obs` against the 'true' mean of the distribution. I am now confused about which 'means' I shall compare.

The mean of a sample I calculated as :

```r
mean_sample <- mean(sample(obs, nsample, T))
```

where `nsample = 20`, for example.

the difference between the `mean_sample` and true mean of the distribution I calculated as:

```r
true_mean <- exp(mS + (sdS^2)/2)
```

and finally

```r
diff <- (true_mean - mean_sample)/true_mean
```

Am I correct in the assumption for `true_mean` and `mean_sample`?